# Magento 500 error after import products

Tags: php, magento

I have a problem with Magento, Version 1.9.0.1. I have imported products with the Magento Dataflow - Profiles around 7000 products. All products are now in stock but I cannot open the Cachee Management I get a 500 error. I already changed the memory_limit 1024M and max_execution_time 16000 but still I get 500 error so what can I do now to enabled the Cache Management

I also delete the Caches manually

So the Backend Compilation page shows also 500 but I disabled the Complier

Comment: try running a full reindex from server command line

Comment: Try using Magento Cleanup Script first to set the correct permissions of all the files inside your Magento setup.

Comment: @Harit but before I made that has the shop works completely

Comment: @Harit now I have a second problem I also cannot edit the products, but the backend is works

Comment: @MagentoNinja I can  full reindex with ssh but the home page is still 500 error also if I want to edit product, but if i open I open a product page on the frontend the it shows me the product

Comment: 500 usually means you are trying to call a method on a nonexisting object. try to enable developer mode or uncomment the ini_set('error_reporting' ... ) line in index.php to view the error. If that won't help, try to remove any product sliders, banners, etc  or informations from the homepage